# Is there any overhead when using value types on heap memory?

Tags: .net, memory-management

Is there any overhead when using value types on heap like pointers, system fields etc.?

Comment: People seem to obsess over the stack and heap when starting out with .NET without realizing that they're mostly just implementation details. What you should focus on is whether what you're producing is *correct*, first. Once you've written some correct code, and set some performance *goals*, then you can *measure* whether your code meets your goals. If it does, great. If it doesn't, *then* start focussing on the areas where the performance is poor. Don't try to learn miilions of arbitrary rules to write "the fastest possible code (which may be incorrect)"

Comment: I'm just trying to gain a deep knowledge of the fundamentals. Knowing more details will help me with my future design tasks. Anyway, I understand your point. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [boxing and unboxing overhead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11856614)

Comment: I agree in spirit @Whirlwind but that particular page may be older than stack overflow.

Comment: I believe what you are saying. Still, link only answers are against the SO rules. Read more here : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific the overhead of boxing is:

- Memory is allocated on the heap
- Two additional members are initialized: type object pointer, sync block index
- The value type fields are copied to the newly allocated heap memory

And unboxing overhead is:

- The address of the boxed object fields in the boxed object is obtained
- The values are copied from the heap to the stack-based object (actually this is not part of the unboxing operation but it usually follows after unboxing)